# How can I ensure secure SSL certificate implementation for cloud services, incorporating best practices and considering key factors?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, https, ssl-certificate, cloud

**prelude:**

As a preamble, I would like to mention that I have implemented a certain approach in my application and have concerns about its security. I seek clarification on whether my application is indeed secure or if there exists a standard that could provide enhanced protection for it.

**Question:**

When developing a program with multiple endpoints and configuring a server set to HTTP, what is the optimal approach to integrating SSL certificates for enhanced security when deploying on cloud services? For instance, if I deploy the application on a VM instance, manage routing, and link an SSL certificate to a load balancer to enable HTTPS on the external URL, is the application inherently secure? Should I have initially started the server with HTTPS in the program itself, necessitating the inclusion of the SSL certificate in the application's/instance's file structure?

Comment: A good answer to your question would be the size of a book. In short, an SSL certificate is just one layer in an onion of security. SSL certificates are used for identity verification and negotiation of encryption keys. SSL certificates protect the client and not your systems. SSL/TLS encrypts traffic, it does not protect you from malicious traffic.